# String literal and string Object memory allocation

Tags: java, string, memory-management, heap-memory

```
String abc= new String ("Hello");//will create new instance
```

and

```
 String abc="Hello";//will not create new instance
```

When the string is created as literal the value "Hello" will be in the string constant pool and the reference  will be in  stack , What about the String object.where does its memory allocation happen?

What does the intern() method do?

Which is more efficient?

Comment: Stack memory is used to store local variables and function call, while heap memory is used to store objects in Java. So String objects are also placed in heap.